# How to Identify Duplicate Records where none of the records have a particular field with NULL

Tags: duplicates

I have 2 tables ([WY WC 2016 Changes TEMP] and [WC_JURIS_CODES]).  I am trying to find records in the 2nd table based on records in the first table, but only records in the 2nd table for the latest EFF_TO date provided that there aren't any other records for that WC_CODE with EFF_TO = NULL.

I started with this SQL:

```
SELECT   OLD.[WC_CODE]
        ,OLD.[EFF_FROM]
        ,OLD.[EFF_TO]
FROM [WY WC 2016 Changes TEMP] NEW  --The SOURCE TABLE
INNER JOIN  [WC_JURIS_CODES] OLD on NEW.[WC_CODE] = OLD.[WC_CODE]
WHERE NEW.[Status] = 'N'  and (OLD.[JURIS_CODE] = 'WY' and OLD.[EFF_TO] is not NULL) or (OLD.[JURIS_CODE] = 'WY' and OLD.[EFF_TO] is NULL)
ORDER BY OLD.[WC_CODE], OLD.[EFF_FROM]
```

This is returning:

```
WC_CODE EFF_FROM    EFF_TO
000010  04/01/2011  12/31/2011
000010  01/01/2012  12/31/2012
000010  01/01/2013  12/31/2013
000010  01/01/2014  12/31/2014
000010  01/01/2015  NULL
000020  04/01/2011  12/31/2011
000020  01/01/2012  12/31/2012
000020  01/01/2013  12/31/2013
000020  01/01/2014  12/31/2014
000030  04/01/2011  12/31/2011
000030  01/01/2012  12/31/2012
000030  01/01/2013  12/31/2013
000030  01/01/2014  12/31/2014
```

I only want to see this result:

```
WC_CODE EFF_FROM    EFF_TO
000020  01/01/2014  12/31/2014
000030  01/01/2014  12/31/2014
```

because it has no other records for WC_CODE = '000030' or '000020' where EFF_TO is null, and these have the latest (most recent) EFF_TO date.

I've tried UNIQUE, DISTINCT but none of that is working.  I believe that I need to identify duplicates and then interrogate them as a group.  No clue whatsoever!  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post `CREATE TABLE` statements for your two tables. Also, which database system is this for? (I don't recognize the `[` `]` syntax.)

Comment: @Alex.  There is no "CREATE TABLE".  Both tables already exist in my database.  I'm using MS SQL Server 2014.

Comment: understood. but seeing the `CREATE TABLE` would help us understand the structure of the tables and thus help give you better answers.

Comment: Here's one...

USE [iStatutory154]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[WY WC 2016 Changes TEMP]    Script Date: 11/25/2015 2:46:54 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WY WC 2016 Changes TEMP](
 [JURIS_CODE] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [WC_CODE] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [WC_DESC] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [2015_Rate] [float] NULL,
 [2016_Rate] [float] NULL,
 [Status] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [Change?] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [F8] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: Here's the other ..
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WC_JURIS_CODES](
 [JURIS_CODE] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [WC_CODE] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
 [EFF_FROM] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [EFF_TO] [datetime] NULL,
 [WC_DESC] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
 [WC_RATE] [decimal](6, 4) NULL,
 [LAST_UPDATED_BY] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
 [LAST_UPDATED_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WC_JURIS_CODES] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [JURIS_CODE] ASC,
 [WC_CODE] ASC,
 [EFF_FROM] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

Comment: Hi. Did my answer work for you? Please it accept if so.

Comment: Hi Alex.  

Yes indeed!  Thank you very, very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query would work for mysql if the brackets were dropped. You may need to adjust for ms sql server.

- In an inner query, find the row with the largest `EFF_FROM` for each `WC_CODE`.
- In the outer query, filter these results to remove rows with `NULL` `EFF_TO` values.

Like this...

```sql
SELECT 
  CODES.[WC_CODE], CODES.[EFF_FROM], CODES.[EFF_TO]
FROM [WC_JURIS_CODES] CODES
INNER JOIN (

  -- build a derived/temporary table with the largest EFF_CODE for each WC_CODE
  -- run this query separately and tweak until it produces the result you want
  SELECT 
    OLD.[WC_CODE], MAX(OLD.[EFF_FROM]) AS MAX_EFF_FROM
  FROM [WY WC 2016 Changes TEMP] NEW
    INNER JOIN [WC_JURIS_CODES] OLD ON (NEW.[WC_CODE] = OLD.[WC_CODE])
  WHERE 
    -- adjust these as needed
    NEW.[Status] = 'N' 
    AND OLD.[JURIS_CODE] = 'WY'
  GROUP BY
    OLD.[WC_CODE]

-- join derived table to main table
) MAX_EFF_FROM ON (CODES.[WC_CODE] = MAX_EFF_FROM.[WC_CODE] AND CODES.[EFF_FROM] = MAX_EFF_FROM.[MAX_EFF_FROM])
-- and remove the NULLs
WHERE
  CODES.[EFF_TO] IS NOT NULL
```

Limitations/caveats:

- The inner query fetches the maximum `EFF_FROM`, since it looks like that value is never null.

  - If you need to fetch the max `EFF_TO` OR a `NULL` `EFF_TO`, you'll also need to ensure that there can be at most 1 `NULL` `EFF_TO` per `WC_CODE`.
  - If the date ranges in these records can overlap, this approach will need to be adjusted. (ie: if the max `EFF_FROM` doesn't always correspond to the max `EFF_TO`)
- `EFF_FROM` should be a unique value per `WC_CODE`. If it isn't, results will be unpredictable. (A unique index on `(WC_CODE, EFF_TO)` would be a good idea if it's possible.)